# T-SQL Trigger After Specific Insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers, insert

I need to write a trigger that only runs when an insertion that has a certain field with a specific value is inserted.  There is no updating.

For example, if I insert an entry that has column X with the value "MAC ID", I want it to run a trigger, but ONLY if the value is "MAC ID".

I know how to test for this normally, but not sure how to test this in a trigger.  So far I've found that I want to use "FOR INSERT", but beyond that I don't know how to implement it.

Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create trigger MaxIdInsert
on YourTable
after insert

as

    if exists
    (
        select *
        from inserted
        where ColumnX = 'MAX ID'
    )
    begin
        -- do what you want here if ColumnX has value of 'MAX ID'
    end

go
```

There's no way to *only* fire a trigger on certain DML specifications (besides `insert`, `update`, and/or `delete`).  Your best bet is to test out the dynamic `inserted` table, which contains records that are inserted into `YourTable`.  In this, you can test for inserted records that have a `ColumnX` value of **"MAX ID"**.

*Edit*: In case you were wondering, I know you specified a `for` trigger in your question.  A `for` trigger is equivalent to an `after` trigger in SQL Server.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly.  Excellent explanation and pretty code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be aware that triggers run once for a batch, not once per row. As such, you may be running in a circumstance in which *some* of the rows match your criteria, and others do not.

As such, you'd do best to write your trigger logic to select the matching rows from `inserted`. If there were no matching rows, the rest of your logic will be working with an empty set, but that's no real problem - SQL Server is plenty fast enough at doing nothing, when required.

E.g. if you're inserting these rows into an audit table, something like:

```
create trigger MacId
on T
for insert
as
    insert into Audit(Col1,Col2,Col3)
    select i.Col1,i.Col2,'inserted'
    from inserted i
    where i.Col4 = 'MAC ID'
```